# php74 erroniously modifying the input stream

Tags: php

I am trying to read from the input stream in PHP, but something is erroneously removing newlines.

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $entries = explode("\n", $data);
    print_r($entries);
?>
```

And the test:

```
$ echo -e "123,a,b,c\n456,d,e,f\n" > test.txt
$ curl http://example.com/test.php --data @test.txt
Array
(
    [0] => 123,a,b,c456,d,e,f
)
```

The expected output should be an array containing each of the new lines, however I only ever get a single element in the array.

How can I stop this incorrect behavior? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with PHP 7.4. cURL converts the new lines.

You could use `--data-binary` in your cURL command, to *"post data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever"* ([source](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary))

```bash
echo -e "123,a,b,c\n456,d,e,f\n" > test.txt
curl http://example.com/test.php --data-binary @test.txt
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123,a,b,c
    [1] => 456,d,e,f
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
)
```

Note that there is 2 end-of-line, because `echo` adds a new line.

Comment: *sigh* yup.. that worked. much appreciated.